# How to change the property text in TinyMCE image plugin?

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I am using the [image](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/image/) plugin in TinyMCE text editor. When I click on the [image](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/image/) plugin, it will display a dialog box with different properties (Image Description, Source etc.)

The image plugin dialog box looks like this,

[image: TinyMCE Image Plugin Dialog Box]

I need to change the "Image Description" text. Or add a tooltip text to the "Image Description" text. How can I achieve that?